# Title of book about an agent who gets miniaturized in order to spy on the Russians?

Tags: story-identification

I read a book back in the late 60s/early 70s about an agent who was miniaturized in order to spy on the Russians, who were doing the same thing (miniaturization). Bits and pieces of what I remember are he and a fellow agent (black female) had an encounter with crows/ravens and two Russian agents were crushed in the mandibles of an ant. Would anyone be able to tell me the name of the book and its author?

Answer (score 6):

[*Cold War in a Country Garden*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1891396.Cold_War_in_a_Country_Garden) (1971) by Lindsay Gutteridge. There are also two sequels, *Killer Pine* (1973) and *Fratricide is a Gas* (1975)